# How to call Java script files multiple times in REACT JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I am making API call form `componentWillMount` method of a class and before the it returns some value the `render` method is called and the script files in `index.html` `body` is been loaded, when the API call returns a value the `render function` is called again but the script files in body of `index.html` not called and thus the javascript functions are not applied to the element that is been rendered newly

for instance, I need an image carousel I am making an API call for the to get a list of image URL while fetching the information some loader is displayed,  upon receiving the response the images are not displayed properly since the javascript files are not called for the second time the elements are not been detected

Is there a better way of implementing API calls or is there any fix for this issue??

Comment: can you post some code

Comment: Can't you just call `render` again after fetching your images?As far as I know, `componentWillMount` is not really meant as an asynchronous thing, more of a 'do stuff thats needed before we mount, like display your loader if you need something async' thing...

Comment: you can use componentDidMount as well

Answer (score 0):

Calling fetch inside componentWillMount will not return before the first render. Therefore the render will be called at least once with empty data.

It might be the problem in your case as well. try fetching inside `componentDidMount` method.

Comment: I was using Axios for API call and then I have changed it to fetch function but still, I face the same issue